# Client did not present a certificate (Postfix)

Tags: centos, ssl, postfix, starttls

I have postfix SMTP relay which have been configured with TLS option. Now just realized when sending email to gmail (for example) using Microsoft outlook,found out this "Client did not present a certificate" on the recipient's mail header
 Received: from MYCOMPUTER (unknown [100.200.100.150]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher (256/256 bits)) (Client did not present a certificate) by smtpserver.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id ABCDE12345 for user@gmail.com
 I am using purchased wildcard SSL cert from Comodo.
 May I know why? Did I configure wrongly? 
 Please help

> smtpd_tls_security_level = may 
>   smtp_tls_security_level = may
>   smtpd_use_tls = yes
>   smtp_use_tls = yes
>   smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
>   smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
>   smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/certs/key.key
>   smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/certs/crt.crt
>   smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/certs/cabundle.ca-bundle
>   smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
>   smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
>   smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
>   smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
>   tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
>   smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
>   smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

`smtp      inet  n       -        n     -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `using TLSv1.2 with cipher (256/256 bits)`

The server supports TLS and the client chose to negotiate a secure TLS connection, all is good there.

> `(Client did not present a certificate)`

The cliënt did not use a TLS client certificate to authenticate itself to the server for [**mutual** TLS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication)  which is very common and no reason to worry, unless you want/need to do mutual TLS

Comment: Hi HBrujin, can i don't want "Client did not present a certificate"? Any config to add in to main.cf ? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You have only configured the use of a certificate for Postfix in the role of the server (i.e. receiving a mail). These are the `smtpd_*` settings.

But the message you refer to is not about receiving mail by your server but about sending mail from your server to another server, i.e. receiving by the other server. In this case usually only the certificate of the receiving mail server gets checked (i.e. the other one) by the sending system (i.e. your Postfix), if TLS is involved at all (your setting considers this optional, i.e. `smtp_tls_security_level = may`).

Some mail servers are configured to not only provide their own certificate for authentication by the sender (i.e. your Postfix) but also to request a certificate from the sender. This is usually optional, i.e. the TLS connection will be accepted even if the sender does not provide such a certificate to authenticate itself. And this is what caused the message *"Client did not present a certificate"*.

If you really want to provide a client certificate you need to explicitly configure at in Postfix with the relevant `smtp_*` settings (not `smtpd_*`), i.e. `smtp_tls_cert_file` etc. See [the documentation](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_cert_key) for details.

Comment: `smtp_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_key_file <br>
smtp_tls_cert_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile`

Answer (score 1):

You've configured Postfix to ask connecting SMTP clients for a client certificate.

```
 smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
```

It's not clear why you have done this, as this is not what you said you want. Perhaps it came from an erroneous Internet tutorial?

In any case, you should be able to remove this line to cause the warning to go away.

Comment: Hi Michael. it showed "No client certificate requested" on recipient's header without " smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes".